# Wait command leaves terminal in a weird state printing white spaces in every line

Tags: bash, docker, terminal, wait

I have a bash script that executes some jobs in the background and prints the output of those jobs with a wait command, modifying the output log. Sometimes after executing the script the terminal works normally but many times happen that the terminal finishes in a weird state, printing many white spaces in every line. What could cause this problem?

Below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# Capture all runnning containers.
database_container=`docker-compose images | sed -n '1,2!p' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | grep -e database`
containers=`docker-compose images | sed -n '1,2!p' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | grep -v database`

if [ -z "$containers" ] ; then
  echo "You need to create the containers first. Execute './chf up'"
  exit;
fi

# Wait until MySQL is running to start installation.
# Do not start installation until database service is running.
echo "Waiting for database in container \"${database_container}\" to become active..."
while ! docker exec ${database_container} mysql --user=db --password=db --host "127.0.0.1" -e 'status' &> /dev/null ; do
    echo "Waiting for database connection..."
    sleep 2
done
echo "Database service active, starting Site installation."

# Separating list of containers in lists of 3 containers to be processed in parallel.
num_containers=`echo $containers | wc -w`
rest=$(($num_containers % 3))
if [ $rest != 0 ] ; then
  limit=$(($num_containers/3))
else
  limit=$(($num_containers/3 - 1))
fi

# Starting installation 3 containers at a time.
containers_list=$containers
for ((i=0; i<=$limit; i++)) {
  P[1]=""; P[2]=""; P[3]=""
  for ((j=1; j<=3; j++)) {
    container=`echo $containers_list | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    if [ -z "$container" ]; then break; fi;
    print_logs=true
    containers_list=`echo $containers_list | awk '{ $1=""; print substr($0,2) }' `
    docker exec -it $container docker-entrypoint.sh | awk -v c="$container" -v j=$(($j+1)) '$0="\033[1;3"j"m" c " > \033[0m"$0' &
    P[$j]=$!
  }
  if [ $print_logs ]; then
    wait ${P[1]} ${P[2]} ${P[3]}
    print_logs=false
    sleep 1
    echo ""
  fi
}

echo "Environment is ready."
```

And below is an example of what happens most of the time after the script finishes execution, with the terminal weirded out. When I execute any command like "ls" this is how it looks. Any ideas?

[Script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMsOQ.png)

Comment: This certainly can't be reproduced with `wait` alone. Indeed, I doubt that `wait` is even *necessary* to reproduce the issue. Please build a [mre] with the *shortest possible code* that reproduces the problem -- and include output as text, rather than images.

Comment: You can probably get a lot of mileage by trying the following: (1) run the script with '-x' (bash -x ...) (2) eliminate the backgrounding/wait, consider strict execution adding '-ue' (`bash -ux`, or `bash -uex`) to identify possible errors, under variables. (3) do 'ps' after the job finish, and see if any background process is still running.